# How to add a UIButton to a UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uibutton

How do I add a UIButton on top of a UIButton?

Such that if I move the the parent UIButton the one on top moves as well.

Comment: Maybe Autolayout is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIButton *testButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
testButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UIButton *smallerButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
smallerButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[testButton addSubview:smallerButton];

[self.view addSubview:testButton];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[oneButton addSubview:otherButton];
```

Remember that `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`...

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *parentBtn;
UIButton *childBtn;

parentBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: // init the button];
childBtn = //same for child btn

[self.view addSubview:parentBtn]; //add the parent button to the view
[parentBtn addSubview:childBtn]; //add the child button on top of the parent button
```